# $C_{c}^\infty\subset \mathcal{S}\subset L^1\cap L^\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis

In this exercice $C_{c}^\infty$ denotes the set of all functions defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are infinitely differentiable and compactly supported.

For this proof it is suggested to use the following statements:

***1. If $\|x\|$ denotes the Euclidean norm of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and if $a>0$, then exists $c>0$ depending only on $n$ and $a$ such that
$$c^{-1}\left(|x_1|^\alpha+\cdots +|x_n|^\alpha\right)\leq \|x\|^\alpha\leq c\left(|x_1|^\alpha+\cdots +|x_n|^\alpha\right)$$.***

***2. $\displaystyle{\int_{B(0,1)}\frac{1}{\|x\|^\alpha}\,dx<\infty\Longleftrightarrow}\hspace{.1cm} a<n\qquad$ and  $\qquad\displaystyle{\int_{B(0,1)^c}\frac{1}{\|x\|^\alpha}\,dx<\infty\Longleftrightarrow}\hspace{.1cm} a>n.$***

(Here $B(0,1)$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Let's see found that $\mathcal{S}\subset L^1\cap L^\infty$. Let $f\in\mathcal{S}$. Since $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so will it be $\quad x_{j}^{n+1}f\quad$ for $j=1,...,n$. Also, because $ f $ is bounded, there is a constant $ c $ such that $$\left(1+|x_1|^{n+1}+\cdots +|x_n|^{n+1}\right)|f(x)|\leq c.$$
by statement ***1*** there is another constant $c'$ such that $$|f(x)|\leq \frac{c'}{1+\|x\|^{n+1}}$$
and for the and by statement ***2,*** $f\in L^1$.

***My questions are about how to test the claims used in this demo. Also I have not been able to demonstrate the inclusion $C_{c}^\infty\subset \mathcal{S}$.***

Comment: The first statement just says that the $\alpha$-norm given by $\|x\|_\alpha=(|x_1|^\alpha+\dots+|x_n|^\alpha)^{1/\alpha}$ and the Euclidean norm are equivalent. Of course that's true for any two norms on $\mathbb R^n$. The second statement can be easily seen by using polar coordinates for the integrals. And the last inclusion follows from the fact that continuous functions (in this case the function and all its derivatives) are bounded on compact sets.

Comment: If $u \in C_c$ then $u$ and all of its derivatives are identically $0$ off some compact set, so $u$ and its derivatives decay faster than any polynomial at infinity trivially

Comment: FYI: one usually uses $C_c^\infty$ to denote the space of smooth, compactly-supported functions, whereas $C_c$ usually denotes continuous functions with compact support.